# Delete a blank line from a file using python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to delete blank lines from text file. Following is my take on it

```
aa=range(1,10)
aa[3]=""
print aa
[1, 2, 3, '', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for i in range(0,len(aa)):
    if aa[i]=="":
        del aa[i]
print lines
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Now I am trying to replicate same methodology on the text file to delete a blank line but it is not working.

```
f=open("sample.txt",'r')
lines=[]
for i in f:
    lines.append(i)

print lines
['In this 30th match\n', '\n', 'there will be no1 winner']

for i in range(0,len(lines)):
    if lines[i]=="":
        del lines[i]

print lines
['In this 30th match\n', '\n', 'there will be no1 winner']
```

Comment: if len(lines[i].rstrip()) < 1 : del lines[i]

Comment: Check these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369440/how-to-delete-all-blank-lines-in-the-file-with-the-help-of-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745854/one-liner-for-removing-blank-lines-from-a-file-in-python , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794245/removing-spaces-and-empty-lines-from-a-file-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if lines[i].isspace():` instead of `if lines[i]=="":`.

Example

```
>>> 'hello'.isspace()
False
>>> '\n'.isspace()
True
```

This should work fine:

```
your_file=open("file_name.ext")
without_blanks=[x for x in your_file if not x.isspace()]
your_file.close()

for line in without_blanks:
    print line
```

Comment: Thanks ForceBru, isspace() works well. Now there is another problem. Once it deletes one line the index of the list items changes and returns an index out of range error. 
for example: 

Deleting 2nd line. third line would take the index of second line and when the loop would reach to last iterations it would fall short of number of lines deleted

Comment: You're iterating over your list in a way that has come from C or C++, I suppose. In Python one should iterate using `for something in iterable:`. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks ForceBru, isspace() works well. Now there is another problem. Once it deletes one line the index of the list items changes and returns an index out of range error. 
for example: 
lines = [1,' ', 3, 5, ' ', 23]

Deleting 2nd item. third item would take the index of second item and when the loop would reach to its last iterations it would fall short of number of lines deleted.
I am thinking of not deleting the blank lines but making a new list with only non-blank lines. 
any other suggestion for this.

Comment: @Abacus, sure, I've already edited my answer, please check it.

Comment: Hey ForceBru, your method works pretty cool. Thanks a lot. Just on a personal note I like to iterate over the index of the list, it helps me visualize the loops more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

First, altering a sequence (deleting elements from it), while iterating is not a good idea.

Also a line that you see as bank is not actually blank, it might contain some *SPACE*, *TAB* (, or other) characters, but (as seen when printing your `line` variable) it will contain an *EOLN* marker: `\n` (or `\r\n`) on *Windows*.

As a result you could modify the code, after first printing lines, do this:

```
lines[:] = [item for item in lines if item.strip()]
```

Comment: Thanks CristiFati, your suggestion is pretty helpful.