# Print raw text to printer using Python in Windows?

Tags: python, printing

I am using Posiflex thermal receipt printer to print retail bills using python.

I tried with following

```
import os

os.startfile("C:/Users/TestFile.txt", "print")
```

but whenever I tried printing there is white space trailing the text resulting in wastage of paper. How can I print just raw text eliminating trailing white space?

please find [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I9pF.png) for clarity.
I want to print it like 2nd one but the output is like the 1st one.

Comment: Well, does `testfile.txt` have trailing whitespace? If so, you'll have to open the file and remove the whitespace.

Comment: What happens when you try printing the same file using the OS instead of python?

Comment: @MorganThrapp No.. testfile.txt has no trailing whitespace

Comment: @NickA I opened the file with notepad and printed... same result

Comment: @prabha korukonda, then the file or printer is the problem, try printing a longer file, it may be that the printer has a minimum print length or that the bottom margin is set too high in the printer settings.  The printer manual should provide some help.

Comment: @NickA I tried printing to **MS OneNote** and observed same behavior. It seems problem is with file type. Can't we just print **raw text** using python instead of writing it to file and print??

Comment: @prabha korukonda Sorry but i can't be of more help, I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @NickA thanks for your response (y)

Answer (score 0):

Strip the extra space:

[one liner for removing blank lines from a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745854/one-liner-for-removing-blank-lines-from-a-file-in-python)

`(.*?)\s*$` will give you capture group 1 as the text stripped of all trailing whitespace. Note: You must use the `s` (single line) flag to include `\n` within `.`

https://regex101.com/r/cgZNHz/2

Comment: there are no trailing whitespaces in text file.. please check comments for more info